# Surface area and volume of a box? Answer must be in rational denominator

Tags: arithmetic, radicals, area

[image: Did I get this this question right?]

Please see if I got the first question right and can I get help with the second one.

Comment: My answer is for volume and surface area times volume by 2(?).

Comment: Shouldn't "half its length" be half of $40\sqrt{10}$? Why does the number $32\sqrt5$ occur in your calculations?